# How to make low poly water with foam effect?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, materials, node-editor

There is a very cool foam effect rising on the shore in this low poly water asset made in Unity:
[image]

And here:
[image]

Is it possible to create a similar effect in Blender?  I have the water material down, I just want a cool foam effect!

Comment: Have you tried adding texture nodes ? Try adding a Musgrave texture and use a colorramp to adjust it, I'm sure it could be mapped to specific places like the shore and even animated.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smArCTzxGpE

Comment: Related question - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201610/is-there-a-way-to-add-foam-around-an-island