# is there a way to add foam around an island?

Tags: shaders, procedural

I'm trying to create a shader that creates a sea foam around an island, is there a way to make it with just the shader?, i'm using an ocean modifier for the sea, and I want to make a factor in the mix shader that mixes by considering the intersecting line between the sea mesh and the islands.

Comment: Something like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/124117/35559)? I know it's very toony, but the same principles may apply to your problem

Answer (score 2):

I achieved the following result.  Apologies for the "before" shot, it's the only thing I have:

[image]

I have this "gulf" scene where my beaches are just planes sticking into the "ocean".  That's a plane with a big *Ocean* modifier and a 20m *Solidify* modifier.

[image]

What I found was that in your ocean's node tree you can use an *Ambient Occlusion* node set to *Inside* and that appears to make it aware of intersections through the final mesh after all the modifiers are calculated.

[image]

I used various methods to add noise to this and used it as the factor of a *Mix Shader* for the surface material.

[image]

Comment: Are you saying the last pic is not a photo? Damn! :)

Comment: Thanks Jachym!  I'm really happy with it from a distance but I'm half tempted to ask a question of my own to seek some help on a detail or two.