# Easy way to add (water) foam lines where 2 mesh meet?

Tags: mesh, materials, shaders, shader-nodes

I've been trying to add foam lines to my water so it doesn't look like its just clipping through the rock, I found another [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201610/is-there-a-way-to-add-foam-around-an-island) about how they did it, but as I am a beginner with blender I can't seem to find out how they did it. Any suggestions help. They did mention that ambient occlusion was detecting the borders.

[image: what I'm trying to get]
Current Shader setup for Water:
[image: Current shader setup]

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the [linked question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/213506/107598) the *Ambient Occlusion* node is used to create the area for the foam - which is actually the calculated shadow.

The *Ambient Occlusion* (AO) node works better in Cycles. Switch the render engine to Cycles, then the viewport shading mode to *Rendered* (shortcut: <kbd>Z</kbd>). In the *Shader Editor* add the *AO* node and a *Color Ramp* node. Check the *Inside* option for the *AO* node.

[image: screenshot 1]

Adjust the slider of the *Color Ramp* so that the shadow looks the way you want it to. The output of the *Color Ramp* can be used as a mask. Use it as *Fac* value for a *MixRGB* node or for another *Color Ramp*.

This way you can use it to control the color, bumpiness, or transparency.

**Important note:** the *AO* does not work very well with transparency (creates black areas), and not well in Eevee, and it's slow in Cycles. In this case, you can bake it into an image with bake type *Emit*. Then *Image Texture* node with the baked AO image replaces the *Ambient Occlusion* node.

[image: screenshot 2]

The water is a flat plane and the land is a displaced plane.